# how to insert data from primary key column to foregin key

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

i am inserting data from a form i want when i will insert data so the first column primary id which is using in second column as a foreign key should be increased

i have tried this code but not working

first table code

```
$this->db->query("insert into af_ads (ad_title,ad_pic,ad_description)
 values ('$title','$filepath','$description')");
```

second table code

```
   $this->db->query("insert into af_category (cat_type,ad_id_fk)
     values ('$category','ad_id')");
```

**NOTE: i want to insert ad_id into ad_id_fk**

Comment: You should use prepared statements.

Comment: @Mike what is prepared statement? kindly share some info

Comment: Do you know what database connection API you are using? See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Comment: So you want to insert the exact key for the inserted record in af_ads as foreign key in af_category?

Comment: @Mike but what is the solution?

Comment: @AfghanWiz yes you are right

Comment: @MuhammadSubhanKhan sure the active record of codeigniter, it creates safer queries

Comment: @MuhammadSubhanKhan! if you found a answer to your question, you are supposed to `accept` it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
// Your first query 
$this->db->query("insert into af_ads(ad_id, ad_title, ad_pic, ad_description)
     values ('', '$title', '$filepath', '$description')");

$ad_id = $this->db->insert_id(); // This returns the id that is automatically assigned to that record

// Use the id as foreign key in your second insert query
$this->db->query("insert into af_category (cat_type,ad_id_fk)
 values ('$category', $ad_id)");
```

Comment: The example code provided in this answer is vulnerable to SQL Injection.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL provides the `LAST_INSERT_ID` function as way to retrieve the value generated for an AUTO_INCREMENT column from the immediately preceding INSERT statement.

A lot of client libraries make this conveniently avaiable (e.g. PDO `lastInsertId` function.)

(I'm not familiar with CodeIgniter or ActiveRecord, so I can't speak to how that's made available.

Your code looks like it's using the PDO interface... but I'm not sure about that.

```
 # either we need to check return from functions for errors
 # or we can have PDO do the checks and throw an exception
 $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

 # attempt insert which will generate AUTO_INCREMENT value
 $this->db->query("INSERT (ad_id, ... ) VALUES (NULL, ...)");

 # if previous insert successfully inserted a row (or rows)
 $ad_id = $this->db->lastInsertId();
```

---

You really need to check whether the previous insert was successful or not. If you aren't going to code that check yourself, then PDO does provide a mechanism that performs this checking automatically, and will throw an exception if a MySQL error occurs.

I've avoided copying your original code, which looks like it's vulnerable to SQL Injection. If you're using PDO, you can make effective use of prepared statements with bind placeholders, rather than including values in the SQL text.